# iCalendar start time difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar

**What is this about**

I'm developing a web application in NodeJS to display information about the agenda of the users which are synchronized with the central server of my University. For that, I wrote a script that downloads an **ICS** file every hour to update my local agenda (stored in an SQLite database).

**What seems to be the problem**

Someone reported to me that some events in their agenda aren't synchronized properly with the University's version, **the start time differs**. Here's the problem. I have an *Event A* and an *Event B* which are **both displayed as starting at 6am UTC** on the university web page. But, when I retrieve them from the server in iCal format, they are represented as such (I've removed the properties unrelated to my issue) :

```
DTSTART:20211108T070000Z <-- starts at 7am UTC
DTEND:20211108T083000Z
SUMMARY:Event A
LOCATION:A room
DESCRIPTION:A description
```

```
DTSTART:20211025T060000Z <-- starts at 6am UTC
DTEND:20211025T073000Z
SUMMARY:Event B
LOCATION:A room
DESCRIPTION:A description
```

**What I already tried**

I've already tried using an open source application (named [OpenWebCalendar](https://open-web-calendar.herokuapp.com)) that displays iCal events to a calendar from a URL and it **displays just like the University agenda.** Both **Event A and B* start at 6am UTC.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find how the app did it be looking into its [source code](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/open-web-calendar/).

> So this problem doesn't come from the University ical file I retrieve.

I've tried looking into the [iCalendar specification document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545) to no avail. I also couldn't find any evidence that this was related to a timezone issue *as all datetime values set in the ical file are in UTC format*.

> So, no problem with the Timezones and I can't find a property or specification that would explain this difference and how to fix it.

I've also written a test script in **NodeJS** in order to retrieve info about the iCal to no avail using [node-ical](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ical). The start time displayed when retrieving the events are the same as in the file which doesn't help at all.

Here's the redacted code if you are interested :

```
const ical = require('node-ical')

let body = `
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//SomeAppName/version 1.0
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20211010T100331Z
DTSTART:20211108T070000Z
DTEND:20211108T083000Z
SUMMARY:Event A
LOCATION:A room
DESCRIPTION:A description
UID:UniqueCodeA 
CREATED:19700101T000000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20211010T100331Z
SEQUENCE:2128343411
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20211010T100331Z
DTSTART:20211025T060000Z
DTEND:20211025T073000Z
SUMMARY:Event B
DESCRIPTION:A description
UID:UniqueCodeB
CREATED:19700101T000000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20211010T100331Z
SEQUENCE:2128343411
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
`

ical.async.parseICS(body, function(err, events){
    console.log(events["UniqueCodeA"])
    console.log(events["UniqueCodeB"])
})
```

**So, my question is**

Is there any iCal specification, properties or any explanation as to why both iCal start times diverge and how to correct them just like OpenWebCalendar does it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the joys of daylight saving changes and timezones.   Somewhere there someone is viewing dates with a timezone set as most people do, this is expected.  There are 2 dates there, and it appears one is one side of a daylight saving change and the other is on the other side.

Unlike UTC some timezones have daylight saving and of course timezones don't change from/to daylight saving at the same time, so lots potential for multiple time differences to appear to be inconsistent across events.

If we take London as an example, on the 8 of November 2021, london time is same as UTC time:

https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?day=8&month=11&year=2021&p1=195&p2=136&iv=0

However on 25 October 2021, at 6am UTC time, London is 7am.

https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?iso=20211025&p2=195&p3=136

Always check what timezones are set on every device and calendar app and be alert around daylight saving changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't take into account daylist saving changes. Actually, now that you point it out, I don't even know why I didn't think about that. That makes perfect sense now !